# How to implement a call-by-reference structure in Python

Tags: python, class, data-structures, pass-by-reference

I'm coding a decision tree and I decided a nice implementation would be a Class/Object structure of the branches (at least in C++). For the sake of simplicity I'm gonna break it down to the *necessary* parts:

```
class DecisionTreeBranch:
    def __init__(self):
         parent      = None
         leftBranch  = None
         rightBranch = None
```

where `parent` declares the way to the super decisions and `leftBranch`, `rightBranch` defines the decisions below.

**What I'm trying to do**:

Now going downwards ain't a problem, but moving upwards: Let's say this tree is defined by the left branches first, so if I end up in a final *leaf*. Im going one step above and take the right branch and continue with the tree building (if I go above, right and left is defined, I'm going another step above, and so on).

The aim is to iterate through the tree by the three parameters: `parent` (up) and `leftBranch`, `rightBranch` (down)

**The problem**

If I'd take e.g. C++ then this wouldn't be a problem, I'd define parent with a *call-by-reference*. But I recently started programming classes in Python, unfortunately I always end up in a *call-by-value* expression, where for sure all the information of the above branches are lost.

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```
[...]
# define way to former branch 
&curDecision.parent = &oldDecision
oldDecision = curDecision

# continue with the next/new decision on the current level
curDecision = DecisionTreeBranch()
[...]
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: What does your python code actually look like? It's not clear how you end up with the problem you are describing.

Comment: @pvg well prettymuch like: `curDecision.parent = oldDecision` and `oldDecision = curDecision`

Comment: In Python, you never handle class instances other than by references to them (it is similar to Java in this respect).  When you pass one of these references to a function, the reference is passed by value.  The function can manipulate the referred-to object via the reference, but it cannot modify the caller's copy of the reference.

Comment: In what way does that not work? In python those would be references to instances, assuming these are instances.

Comment: @pvg are you sure? Well then my code seems to have a bug. Right now I only can go 1 level upwards - that's why I'm guessing it's call-by-value in this case

Comment: I am quite sure. All instances in python are heap allocated. When you assign one to a variable, the variable ends up being a name for a reference to the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the example of call by reference. You can also see that as multiple constructors cannot be used in python, so Keyword arguments are used in the **init** method:

```
class Maximum:
    def __init__(self,x = None,y = None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def max(self,Maximum):
        if Maximum.x > Maximum.y:
            print('{0} is maximum.'.format(Maximum.x))
        else:
            print('{0} is maximum.'.format(Maximum.y))

m1 = Maximum()
m2 = Maximum(3,8)
m1.max(m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass a dictionary with keys parent, left, right. You will be able to modify the dictionary and access the structure by keys.

Comment: I guess dictionary implementation is something different than class/objects (?)

Comment: You can always pass a list of 1 element with your object in it. Then you can continue to use the class objects.

Comment: @user3085931, not at all -- or at least not in any way that makes a difference to your question.  In the scheme RobertJacobs proposes, a reference to the dictionary would be passed by value.  The called function could modify its contents, which modifications would be visible to the caller, but it could not cause the caller's reference to point to a different dictionary.